Change Dock appearance at system level
I love the 3D effect of the Dock that OS X used (until 10.9), and I'm looking for a way to change the appearance of my Dock to that old style.
I looked into com.apple.dock.plist, but nothing related to the appearance of the Dock itself. I also can't find a background file in Dock.app > Contents > Resources.
Which files should I modify to change the theme used by the Dock?
Note: I don't want to use tools like cDock.
